# Attribute error: 'bool' object has no attribute 'signal'

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, signals-slots

I am working on a PyQT application and I am stuck trying to implement a CV class into its framework. Here is the class with the issue, and where the error originates.

```
class ShowVid(QObject):
    signal = pyqtSignal(QImage)        

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def startVideo(self):
        camera_port = 0
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)          
        run_video = True
        while run_video:
            ret, image = camera.read()
            color_swapped_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            height, width, _ = color_swapped_image.shape
            qt_image = QImage(color_swapped_image.data,
                              width,
                              height,
                              color_swapped_image.strides[0],
                              QImage.Format_RGB888)

            self.signal.emit(qt_image)
```

I receive the error:

```
self.signal.emit(qt_image)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'signal'
Abort trap: 6
```

Update with code from Main and VidViewer class. The VidViewer class paints the image from the frame captured with the camera. Frames are refreshed by the setImage slot. The main class structures the widgets with the layout and runs the application.

```
class VidViewer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.image = QImage()        
        self.initUI()

    def paintEvent(self, _):
        print("paint image")
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
        self.paintImage = QImage()

    def initUI(self):
        print("INIT UI")  
        #image = self.image
        self.push_button = QPushButton("Start")

        self.push_button.clicked.connect(ShowVid.startVideo)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.push_button, 0, 0,1,1) 

        self.setLayout(self.layout) 
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.image = image
        self.paintEvent()


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.viewer = VidViewer()
        self.vid = ShowVid()

        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.viewer)       
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.viewer) 

        self.vid.signal.connect(self.viewer.setImage)  

        self.setGeometry(10,10,1280,720)        
        self.setFixedSize(1280,720) 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
run = Main()   
run.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: super().__init__() to super(ShowVid, self).__init__() ?

Comment: Your code is not MCVE.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The error means that `self` has been assigned a boolean value somewhere (True/False.. or more likely... None).. your code does not tell us how that happened.  Most likely, your `self`definition is not valid in the scope you are using it.

Comment: I have executed like this and I have not had problems, you could show a code that can be executed and can reproduce your error.

Comment: @SurestTexas I do not see where self is being redefined or becomes invalid. I will post the code for my other two classes now.

Comment: Guess: `self.push_button.clicked.connect(ShowVid.startVideo)` does not use an instance of `ShowVid`, hence the first argument to `startVideo` is not `self`, but just whatever the gui passes (apparently, a bool). Thus, in the actual method, `self` becomes that bool, causing the error. (It may also depend somewhat on what the `@pyqtSlot()` decorator does.)

Comment: @Evert thanks. I am certain you are right. I don't know how to call functions across class any other way... Should it be handled in Main?

Comment: @Sleepy-Z. Surely the `ShowVid` object should be an attribute of the `VidViewer`, rather than the main window? If you do it that way, connecting the signals is much easier.